# Getting syntax error when running "rails new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to create a new project by running:

```
rails new app
```

I get the following error message:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require': /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
      @has_args    = !exception.args&.empty?
                                      ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/did_you_mean.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/error.rb:4:in `<class:Thor>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/error.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/cli.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure what's going on. What's this?

Comment: Try to reinstall ruby then rails and then try, what happens?

Comment: Upgrade your Ruby to at least 2.3, that's when the safe navigation operator (`&.`) was added: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/

Answer (score 1):

The safe navigation operator `&.` is invalid in Ruby < 2.3. And you are using Ruby 2.2. That is the cause of the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rvm and then install rails.

```
rvm install 2.5.0
```

Reference : https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: Why Ruby 2.5.0 now? It is neither the oldest required for `&.`, nor the newest available.

Comment: I have tried in my local system for rails new app. it is working fine. so i suggested.